# android: disable clicks from ViewSwitcher's inactive child view

Tags: android, click

I have a custom ViewSwitcher with a flip animation. The problem is that the view that's not currently shown (that contains child buttons) is intercepting the clicks from the active view. I've tried to set the visibility to invisible or gone (didn't work), I tried iterating through all child view and setting setClickable(false) and that didn't work.

Maybe I'm applying my changes in the wrong place? Below is the relevant sections of my code.

```
public class ViewFlip3D extends ViewSwitcher {
    // switches views
    public void flip() {
        float centerX = getWidth() / 2.0f;
        float centerY = getHeight() / 2.0f;

        Flip3D animOut = new Flip3D(-90, 0, centerX, centerY);
        animOut.setDuration(500);
        animOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animOut.setFillAfter(true);

        Flip3D animIn = new Flip3D(0, 90, centerX, centerY);
        animIn.setDuration(500);
        animIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animIn.setFillAfter(true);

        animIn.setAnimationListener(new ShowNextView(this, animOut));

        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getCurrentView();

        // Disable clicks here!
        // like: view.DisableClicksFromAllChildViews();

        view.startAnimation(animIn);
    }

    private final class ShowNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            container.showNext();
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) container.getCurrentView();
            view.startAnimation(flipin);

            // Enable clicks here!
            // like: view.EnableClicksFromAllChildViews();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? Even I am facing a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove fill after or call clearAnimation when you want the view out of the way.

If none of these suit your needs you can recursively loop the children and set clickable to false.